# When using 'bundle exec rake db:create', rake always aborts How to solve?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rakefile

Every time I execute `bundle exec rake db:create` I'm always getting this error in the terminal:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- /Users/davidnoldner/Documents/GitHub/RatatamBot/rakefile/User/Documents/RatatamBot
/Users/davidnoldner/Documents/GitHub/RatatamBot/rakefile:1:in `require'
/Users/davidnoldner/Documents/GitHub/RatatamBot/rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/davidnoldner/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/davidnoldner/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/davidnoldner/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've been stuck at this since yesterday and was looking for the answer often here on Stackoverflow but didn't find any solution matching to my problem. That's kinda frustrating. I really need your help.

Rakefile:

```
  require File.expand_path('/Users/davidnoldner/Documents/GitHub/RatatamBot/rakefile', __FILE__)
  require 'rake'
  require 'resque/tasks'

+ # temp fix for NoMethodError: undefined method `last_comment'
+ # remove when fixed in Rake 11.x
+ module TempFixForRakeLastComment
+   def last_comment
+     last_description
+   end 
+ end
+ Rake::Application.send :include, TempFixForRakeLastComment
+ ### end of temfix
+ 
  task "resque:preload" => :environment

  Rails.application.load_tasks
```

Comment: The error says it cannot find the file at line 1. Check the expanded path is right and the file exists.

Comment: The file is in the RatatamBot folder

Comment: the first line generates this path `/Users/davidnoldner/Documents/GitHub/RatatamBot/rakefile/User/Documents/RatatamBot` which is obviously wrong, you have a /Users/... appended to the first path which makes no sense, fix that path and it should work (I don't really understand why are you requiring that file which look like it's the file you are actually in, what are you trying to do with that code?)